# Error when removing kernel 4.8.0-39

Tags: linux-mint, kernel

One day I choose to install kernel 4.8.0-39 but it does not and return error, I didn't give it a value. But now I want to install updates and terminal show errors related with it, checking /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/make.log file I found next:

```
/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/wrapndis.c: In function ‘tx_worker’:
/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/wrapndis.c:707:16: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’
    wnd->net_dev->trans_start = jiffies;
                ^
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target «/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/wrapndis.o» failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/wrapndis.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target «_module_/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build» failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build] Error 2
make: exit from directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic»
```

If I understand correctly kernel can not compile and return error because of what all upgrade crashes. What do I need to do to remove all mention about 4.8.0-39 kernel?

I've already tried to run:

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic`
2. `sudo apt autoremove`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
4. `sudo apt-get install -f`
5. `sudo apt remove linux-headers-4.8.0-39`

and everytime I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-headers-4.8.0-39' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 162 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 383195 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic (4.8.0-39.42~16.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.8.0-39-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.8.0-39-generic cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic/build or /lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic/source.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic
Warning: No support for locale: ru_RU.utf8
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_jTYeTT/lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_jTYeTT/lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My system:

```
Linux PCNAME 4.4.0-63-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 1 17:20:32 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Release:    18.1
Codename:   serena
```

---

*EDITED:*

```
~$ ll -d /var/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 42 root root 4096 мар  2 02:12 /var/tmp/
```

`df -h`

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev 7,7G 0 7,7G 0% /dev
tmpfs 1,6G 9,6M 1,6G 1% /run
/dev/sda2 48G 13G 34G 28% /
tmpfs 7,7G 207M 7,5G 3% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5,0M 4,0K 5,0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 7,7G 0 7,7G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3 268M 261M 0 100% /boot
/dev/sda4 149G 138G 8,1G 95% /home
cgmfs 100K 0 100K 0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs 1,6G 44K 1,6G 1% /run/user/1000
```

@Bruno9779 Yeah, seems like you absolutely right, my */boot* haven't enough space, I forgot, that */boot* on another partition, but I can't delete something because `apt-get` tries to delete *4.8.0-39* kernel first and crashes, I wanted to delete some kernels manually, but decided to don't touch anything while it works. For now I have *4.4.0-53* *4.4.0-59* *4.4.0-62* *4.4.0-63* *4.4.0-64* installed kernels and boot from 4.4.0-64

Comment: apart from the obvious answer, that your disk may be full, if not please post `ll -d /var/tmp/`

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

Confirm the issue with:

```
df -h
```

The error messages generated as a result of "out of disk space" are often misleading.

**EDIT:**

Apparently your boot partition is full.

```
/dev/sda3 268M 261M 0 100% /boot
```

You need to make some space there before you can install/reinstall any kernel.

Get a list of installed kernels:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Get the version number of the running kernel:

```
uname -r
```

Now remove some unused kernels with the package manager

Comment: I edited my answer. You should put the output of df -h in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to everybody who helps. I solve my problem. As Bruno9779 wrote I needed more free space on */boot* partition I made backup of my installed kernel images *4.4.0-53, 59, 62* and delete *4.8.0-39* after that return backuped files and remove them too through synaptic.